With CSS, is it possible to sort the z-index for multiple mangled objects?
I have started to build an hexagonal map using the oi.hexmap.js library as shown in this JSFiddle.
I have an issue with conflicting z-index that I'm not sure can even be solved.
I have a base div with id="hexmap1" which host the map. Inside that div, I have another one  with id="compass" which has a background picture.
<div id="hexmap1">
    <div id="compass"></div>
</div>

The library creates an hex grid inside hexmap1 which goes over compass because it's executed (The javascript) after everything in the DOM has been loaded. So I bump the z-index of compass to have it above the hex grid (Because this is what I want).
When you hover over an hex, it gets a new class hover which I use to make it bigger and more visible. However, if an hex is close enough to compass, when hovered it will appear behind compass which is logical.
#compass {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 30px; 
    left: 30px; 
    width: 67px; 
    height: 71px; 
    z-index: 2;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/50)
}

So I tried to bump the z-index of the hex using different ways:

By selecting #hexmap1 .hover path
By selecting .hex:hover


#hexmap1 .hover path { 
    stroke-width: 4px; 
    transform: scale(1.75); 
    stroke: black; 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}

.hex {
    position: absolute;
    /* Default z-index for normal hexes */
    z-index: 1;
}

.hex:hover {
    z-index: 3; /* Move hovered hex above the compass */
}

None of that worked and I'm wondering if that's even possible to get the behavior I'm looking as the hexes are children of the hex grid.
Is there a solution to this problem or it's simply impossible the way the things are built?
What I want is that normal hexes stay under the compass <div> but that they move above that same div if hovered over.


hex = new OI.hexmap(document.getElementById('hexmap1'),{
  // Define the HexJSON - https://open-innovations.org/projects/hexmaps/hexjson
  'grid': {'show':true},
  'label': {
    'show': true,   // Show a label
    'clip': true, 
    format: txt => `Hex: ${txt}`
  },
  'hexjson':{
    "layout":"odd-q",
    "originPoint": "left-top",
    "hexes": {
      "G":{"n":"0,0","q":0,"r":0,"class":"swirl"},
      "A":{"n":"0,1","q":0,"r":1,"class":"chevron"},
      "B":{"n":"1,0","q":1,"r":0,"class":"mario"}
    }
  }
});
#hexmap1 { 
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

#hexmap1 .hex path {
    stroke: #817B58; 
    stroke-width: 1; 
}

#hexmap1 .hover path { 
    stroke-width: 4px; 
    transform: scale(1.75); 
    stroke: black; 
    position: absolute;
}

.hex {
    position: absolute;
    /* Default z-index for normal hexes */
    z-index: 1;
}

.hex:hover {
    z-index: 3; /* Move hovered hex above the compass */
}

#compass {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 30px; 
    left: 30px; 
    width: 67px; 
    height: 71px; 
    z-index: 2;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/50)
}
<script src="https://open-innovations.github.io/oi.hexmap.js/dist/oi.hexmap.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hexmap1">
        <div id="compass"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="oi.hexmap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




try setting  z-index only on hover if not required otherwise. position(but static) and transform do already bring up front these elements.

Please add a [mcve] to your question.

To answer the question: no, CSS is not able to sort anything. It is not a programming language.

@Kosh Doesn't the JSFiddle count as an example?

JSFiddle is nice, but it's external and might become unavailable. You could add a runnable code snippet in your question directly using <> button on the editor toolbar.

Oh, that's great. I wasn't aware of this possibility.
I will update my question then. Or should I open a new one instead?
